# Отступ на новой строке после запятой при объявлении переменных

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отступы

Проверил каждую опцию в настройках Visual Studio, по-разному пробовал гуглить... Как сделать, чтобы выравнивание автоматически срабатывало как на втором скриншоте, то есть с отступом после типа? Сейчас, при переносе после запятой, ввод начинается с самого начала строки

[image]
[image]

Comment: Добавлю, что в CLion clang-format уже [интегрирован](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clangformat-as-alternative-formatter.html#clion-support) и можно одной кнопкой сгенерить конфигурацию по текущим настройкам форматирования 

Comment: @dIm0n при чем сдесь clion? Речь же о вижле... Что касается интеграции clang-format - это утилита в unix стиле приспособленная для использования в конвеерах, так что интеграция - простейшее дело

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch просто реклама хорошей IDE вместо VS

Comment: @dIm0n не совсем уместно (но настаивать не буду). Я вот вообще без IDE обхожусь и считаю что зло, особенно в руках не опытных программистов, которые из-за них не знают банальных вещей (вроде как устроен процесс компиляции) и оказываются привязаны к решениям, специфичным даже не для системы, а для конкретной IDE (в этом мы с вами согласны, что VS - *****). Я вот вообще пользуюсь __vim__

Answer (score 3):

И снова проблемы форматирования... К счастью уже давно есть отличное решение, не зависящее от IDE или ОС: **clang-format**. Он отлично инегрируется с любой IDE и даже простыми редакторами, не говоря о том, что его можно запускать как отдельную прогу (собственно в плагинах он и запускается, как правило, как отдельная программа). Вам нужно лишь определиться с используемым форматом (google, mozilla, llvm и пр.) или описать свой (в файле .clang-format)

Comment: Блин, а кто-нибудь может объяснить за что был поставлен минус?...

Answer (score 1):

Следует объявлять по одной переменной за раз:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```